# $.each with delay() over JSON source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I iterate through JSON with $.each() using delay()?

 I want each image to show for 3 seconds using fadeIn() and fadeOut().

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8x6rR/23/

```
// JSON source
var sponzorji = [{
    logo: "http://dijaki.gimvic.org/2a/stara/miha/javascript/slider/img/interspar.png",
    link: "http://www.center-vic.si/",
    naziv: "Interspar Vič"
}, {
    logo: "http://dijaki.gimvic.org/2a/stara/miha/javascript/slider/img/plesna_sola_urska.png",
    link: "http://www.urska.si/",
    naziv: "Plesna Šola Urška"
}, {
    logo: "http://dijaki.gimvic.org/2a/stara/miha/javascript/slider/img/sae.png",
    link: "http://ljubljana.sae.edu/sl/home/",
    naziv: "SAE Ljubljana"
}];

// HTML
var linkEl = $("a#link"),
    imgEl = $("img#slika");

    // mainLoop
    function mainLoop() {
        $(sponzorji).each(function (index) {

            linkEl.attr("href", this.link).find(imgEl).attr({
                src: this.logo,
                alt: this.naziv
            });

            // Recursive
            if (index == sponzorji.length - 1) {
                mainLoop();
            }

        });

    } // end mainLoop

mainLoop();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to run continuously even after you reached the end of array then it would be best to use a setInterval(). You can then use an incriminator to keep count of the next json object and using modulus and .length you can start back from 0 when you reach the last item. Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x6rR/25/).

```
var linkEl = $("a#link"),
    imgEl = $("img#slika"),
    inc = 0;

imgEl.hide();

function mainLoop() {
    setInterval(function () {
        imgEl.fadeOut(function () {
            inc = inc % sponzorji.length
            linkEl.attr("href", sponzorji[inc].link).find(imgEl).attr({
                src: sponzorji[inc].logo,
                alt: sponzorji[inc].naziv
            }).fadeIn();
        });
        inc++
    }, 3000);
}
mainLoop();
```

Comment: it work, just one question. why are you using inc % sponzorji.lenth? thanks

Comment: `%` is a modulus operator, it divides the value and returns the remainder. `inc` is just an incrementer, and `sponzorji.length` is total number of objects. So 0 divided by 3 has a remainder of 0, 1/3 = 1, 2/3 = 2, then 3/3 has a remainder of 0 so it starts over. And so on: 4/3=1,5/3=2,6/3=0,7/3=1. Instead of using that it can also be achieved by using: `if (inc < 2){inc++}else{inc = 0}` OR using a ternary operator 1 line again: `inc = inc < 2 ? inc++ : 0`. In both examples you can remove the inc++ at end of function.

Answer (score 0):

$.each(function(i,e) {}) include the "i" parameter which is the index of the current item.  The best way to do this would be to add that index in the calculation of the delay(). I'm pretty positive on the fact that you can delay a ".fadeIn()" animation using .delay(time).fadeIn().  So if you want to fadeIn() something and then fadeOut after 3 seconds, you should do something like this:

```
$(something with images).each(function(i,e) {
   // i*3800 returns 0 on the first index, which starts the animation automaticly.
   // 3800 is 3seconds + 400 fadeIn() animation + 400 fadeOut() animation
   // fadeOut() animation is in the callback so the 3seconds 'delay' should be set there.
   $(this).delay(i*3800).fadeIn(400, function() {
      $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
   })
})
```

Hope this helps.